# Understanding Rails controller - view connection via instance variable of associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, view, controller, associations, instance-variables

I am a newbie trying to understand how to use properly the instance variables of associated models in the controller to make them available for the view. How does this work? Is there a standard ? I keep getting undefined method errors. What's the proper usage of @example = Example.find(params[:id]) or @example = Example.find(example_params) ? for associated models? Does each controller action have specific @instance variable formulas (i.e Example.all for index ) ?
Does anyone know of a comprehensive guide on controller view usage of instance variables?

CODE

MODEL

```
class Presupuesto < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :cliente
      has_many :ordenes, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :medios, :through => :ordenes
      has_one :factura
      validates :fecha, :titulo, :cliente_id, :producto, presence: true
    end

    class Factura < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :factura_items
       belongs_to :cliente
       belongs_to :presupuesto
       validates :fecha_de_expedicion, presence: true
    end
```

VIEW

```
   _form.html.erb
<% content_for :title do %>Factura<% end %>
    <h3>Factura</h3>
    <div class="form">
      <%= simple_form_for @factura do |form| %>
        <%= form.error_notification %>
        <%= form.input :fecha_de_expedicion %>
        <%= form.association :cliente, :label_method => :nombre,  label: "Cliente", :include_blank => false %>
        <%= form.association :presupuesto, :label_method => :titulo,  label: "Presupuesto", :include_blank => false %>
        <%= form.button :submit, 'Submit', class: 'submit' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    new.html.erb
    <h1>New Factura</h1>

    <%= render 'form' %>

    <%= link_to 'Back', facturas_path %>
```

CONTROLLER

```
class FacturasController < ApplicationController

      # GET /facturas
      # GET /facturas.json
      def index
        @factura = Factura.all
        @cliente = Cliente.all
      end
      # GET /facturas/1
      # GET /facturas/1.json
      def show
        @factura = Factura.find(params[:id])
        @cliente = @factura.cliente
        @presupuesto = @factura.presupuesto
      end
      # GET /facturas/new
      def new
       @factura = Factura.new
       @presupuesto = Presupuesto.all
       #@ordenes = Ordene.where(aprobado_por_cliente: 1) 
      end
      # GET /facturas/1/edit
      def edit
      end
      # POST /facturas
      # POST /facturas.json
      def create
        @factura = Factura.new(factura_params)
        respond_to do |format|
          if @factura.save
            format.html { redirect_to @factura, notice: 'Factura was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @factura }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @factura.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end`
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /facturas/1
      # PATCH/PUT /facturas/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @factura.update(factura_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @factura, notice: 'Factura was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @factura }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @factura.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /facturas/1
      # DELETE /facturas/1.json
      def destroy
        @factura.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to facturas_url, notice: 'Factura was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_factura
          @factura = Factura.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def factura_params
          params.require(:factura).permit(:fecha_de_expedicion, :cliente_id, :presupuesto_id )
        end
    end
```

**ERROR
    NoMethodError at /facturas/new
    undefined method `presupuesto_id' for #**

```
Started GET "/facturas/new" for ::1 at 2015-05-30 21:06:26 -0500
Processing by FacturasController#new as HTML
  Cliente Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "clientes".* FROM "clientes"
  Presupuesto Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "presupuestos".* FROM "presupuestos"
  Rendered facturas/_form.html.erb (21.1ms)
  Rendered facturas/new.html.erb within layouts/application (22.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 29ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `presupuesto_id' for #<Factura:0x007feadf9dc930>:
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb:28:in `value'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/collection_select.rb:16:in `block in render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/collection_select.rb:16:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:202:in `collection_select'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:789:in `collection_select'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/inputs/collection_select_input.rb:9:in `input'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/wrappers/leaf.rb:19:in `render'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/wrappers/many.rb:28:in `block in render'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/wrappers/many.rb:26:in `render'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/wrappers/root.rb:15:in `render'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:115:in `input'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:191:in `association'
  app/views/facturas/_form.html.erb:8:in `block in _app_views_facturas__form_html_erb___1959803079335200881_70323378590380'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:444:in `form_for'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:26:in `block in simple_form_for'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:45:in `with_simple_form_field_error_proc'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:25:in `simple_form_for'
  app/views/facturas/_form.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_facturas__form_html_erb___1959803079335200881_70323378590380'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
  app/views/facturas/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_facturas_new_html_erb___1900732511694118275_70323400237940'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support
  :in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/davefogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  action
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Any instance variable defined in a controller method will be available in the view rendered by that method. Please post the actual code you're using and the complete text of any error messages you're getting.

Comment: Please let me know if you need something else. I am truly confused on what to do to make the code go through.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an undefined method #presupuesto_id in your view, specifically in app/views/facturas/_form.html.erb line 8. This may have to with the required params being commented out at the bottom of your controller file or that you are trying to call the method(presupuesto_id) on the wrong object (@factura).It would also be helpful to see both of the rendered views in order to see how the objects are being passed i.e _form.html.erb and new.html.erb.

This write up gives a decent explanation of the controller/view relationship as well as an explanation of the instance variable within each action. http://www.sitepoint.com/building-your-first-rails-application-views-and-controllers/

Try to change the form to look for the id of presupuesto instead of the title. If that works then you need to add a new method or scope to the Factura model that will find the presupuesto with a name like 'title' and assign it to the newly  created instance of Factura.

```
        <%= form.association :cliente, :label_method => :nombre,  label: "Cliente", :include_blank => false %>
    <%= form.association :presupuesto, :label_method => :nombre,  label: "Presupuesto", :include_blank => false %>
```